# Unix awk deleting every two lines

Tags: unix, awk

Basically I need to print 2 lines then delete two lines and so on.

```
awk 'BEGIN {count = 0} if(count == 4){count = 0} else if(count <= 1) {print,count++} else {count++}' f4
```

I am getting syntax errors.

or

```
awk '{count = 0; if(count == 4)count = 0; else if(count <= 1) print count++; else count++;}' f4
```

It prints all zeros.

I've also tried

```
awk 'NR%3 && NR%4' f4
```

Which is close but multiples of 3 and 4 are not printed.

Thanks

EDIT: GOT IT!

```
awk 'BEGIN{count = 0};{ if(count == 3)count = 0; else if(count <= 1) {print; count=count+1;} else count=count+1;}' f4
```

Comment: `awk 'NR%3 && NR%4' f4` this was close to a working solution, see my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be one of the shortest and simplest to explain

```
awk 'NR%4==1 || NR%4==2'
```

`NR%4==1` would print every `forth` line starting at `one`
`NR%4==2` would print every `forth` line starting at `two`
`||` this is an logical `or`

Given this file

```
cat file
one 1
two 2
three 3
four 4
five 5
six 6
seven 7
eight 8
nine 9
ten 10
eleven 11
twelve 12
thirteen 13
fourteen 14
fifteen 15
sixteen 16
seventeen 17
eighteen 18
nineteen 19
twenty 20
```

```
awk 'NR%4==1 || NR%4==2' file
```

Gives:

```
one 1
two 2
five 5
six 6
nine 9
ten 10
thirteen 13
fourteen 14
seventeen 17
eighteen 18
```

---

A variation using `&&`

```
awk 'NR%4 && NR%4!=3'
```

Comment: Or in short `NR%4~/[12]/`

Answer (score 2):

Use `getline` function to read following lines and discard those that you don't want to print:

```
awk '{ print; getline; print; getline; getline }' infile
```

Comment: @Nexus: You should then, because it's a powerful command for any `awk` coder.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
awk 'int((NR-1)/2)%2 == 0'
```